# LINQ: SQL optimised query for basic generic types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get LINQ to generate SQL optimised code for comparing basic generic types.

In short: I want the code below to be SQL optimised, e.g. generate the SQL query `select * from X where X_ID == id`.

```
public async Task GetByIdAsync(long id)
{
    var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

The problem is that this does not happen, because `i.Id` is a generic type (see below), so LINQ does not know how to handle it.

Full demonstration code, with errors in comments.

```
public interface IBaseEntity<TIdType>
{
    TIdType Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass<TEntity, TIdType>
    where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity<TIdType>
    // TIdType will be a basic numeric type like short and int.
    where TIdType : struct, IConvertible
{
    public async Task GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        // This is the best solution I could find for comparing basic generic types.
        // However, it is not SQL optimised, so it will be evaluated in code.
        var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id.ToInt64(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) == id);
    }

    public async Task CompileErrorAsync(TIdType id)
    {
        // Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TIdType' and 'TIdType'
        var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

        // Using "dynamic" also won't work. Error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.
    }

    public async Task RuntimeFailureAsync(long id)
    {
        // Runtime warning: Possible unintended use of method Equals(object) for arguments of different types ... This comparison will always return 'false'.
        var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => id.Equals(i.Id));

        // Runtime warning: Possible unintended use of method Equals(object) for arguments of different types in expression 'i.MC_CODEID.Equals(Convert(__id_0, Object))'. This comparison will always return 'false'.
        var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id.Equals(id));

        // CompareTo() also fails: System.ArgumentException: Object must be of type Int64.
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: This question has two valid answers, one where you [manually build the expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67920144/371917), and another where [every child class has an override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67921403/371917) to handle it's own unique case. My final solution borrowed from both.

Comment: In the second method `CompileError(TIdType id)` why you can't use `SingleOrDefault(i => i.Equals(id))`? you know `TIdType` is `struct` and ``Equals` must be work

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way out is to make several method overloads explicitly specifying the desired types: short, int, long, etc. That's how it's always done. See, for example, [Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0) method overloads.

Comment: And you can use ` Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>> criteria` and apply  criteria in your `SingleOrDefaultAsync` method

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I'm comparing the ID within `i`, so no. `i` is of type `TEntity`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov It's a bit complicated because the template type is not the method input, but the ID inside of the template class. I will try some tests to see if I cannot find a way to do this anyway...

Comment: They are usually called *generic* types, not template types. Why are you using a generic type as the `ID` anyway, perhaps you should just settle on one type?

Comment: @Charlieface I will update the wording of my question. The thing is, the generic ID type is the only way to reduce LOTS of duplicate code. The database has different ID types, so I cannot just pick one and roll with it.

Comment: And does [@AlirezaAhmadi 's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917294/linq-sql-optimised-query-for-basic-generic-types?noredirect=1#comment120046484_67917294) not work, like this `SingleOrDefault(i => i.id.Equals(id))`?

Comment: @Charlieface No. I updated the question with the warning message.

Comment: No no pu that code in `CompileError(TIdType id)`

Comment: It actually compiles without any errors.

Comment: I might have something. Have a look at my attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67921403/371917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to use Expression Tree generation to make query work as expected. Simplified your class:

```cs
public class TestClass<TEntity, TIdType>
    where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity<TIdType>
    // TIdType will be a basic numeric type like short and int.
    where TIdType : struct, IConvertible
{
    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var entity = await GetFilteredById(id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    private IQueryable<TEntity> GetFilteredById(long id)
    {
        var query = DB.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, nameof(IBaseEntity<TIdType>.Id));
        Expression idExpr;

        if (prop.Type != typeof(long))
            idExpr = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(id, prop.Type));
        else
            idExpr = Expression.Constant(id);

        var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Equal(prop, idExpr), param);
        return query.Where(predicateLambda);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know one could write code like this. I will definitely use this somewhere.

Comment: Actually EF queries are based on the Expression Tree. So, if you can build Expression Tree - you can create any query dynamically.

Comment: Okay cool. And if I only want the expression, I would just omit the "DB.Set<>" and "query.Where()" parts.

Comment: Yep. Even more you can call `Where` dynamically or any supported method. It is also Expression Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Running with the idea of overloads and expressions (from the comments), this is more or less what I came up with.

```
public abstract class TestClass<TEntity, TIdType, TModel>
    where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity<TIdType>
    where TIdType : struct, IConvertible // I probably don't need this line any more.
    where TModel : class IBaseModel<TIdType>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetSingleEntityWhereClause(TModel model);

    public async Task TestMethodAsync(TModel model)
    {
        var test = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(GetSingleEntityWhereClause(model));
    }
}

public class SampleImplementation : TestClass<Sample, short, SampleModel>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> GetSingleEntityWhereClause(SampleModel model)
    {
        return p => p.Id == model.Id;
    }
}
```

And then, if I want to implement this for a specific type.

```
public abstract class TestClass<TEntity, TIdType, TModel>
    // ...
{
    // ...

    public async Task GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        model.Id = GetIdTypeValue(id);
        var entity = await DB.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(GetSingleEntityWhereClause(model));
    }

    private static TIdType GetIdTypeValue(object id)
    {
        var type = typeof(TIdType);

        if (type == typeof(short))
        {
            return (dynamic)Convert.ToInt16(id);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            return (dynamic)Convert.ToInt32(id);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unknown ID type \"{0}\"", type));
        }
    }
}
```